# Page cannot be found when access rest api throught broweser

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, 404, page-not-found

Hi everyone have an issue when attempt to access restful api through browser with basic request as picture below instead of xml result:
[image]

it also occurs on CSOM  the error returns : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found, anyone have faced with this problems, please help me.

Comment: What is URL of web application in Central Administrator? Your URL looks like you browse site from IIS directly.

Comment: it was http://[pc-name]:port , but it worked fine when i used localhost:port, just cannot browse to _api/web, the original url aslo

Comment: Can you please try with pc-name URL instead of localhost

Comment: regretfully, i have tried already but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

It has any problems when i get 401 error before it return 404 ?
[image]

Comment: Do you have permission? It is related to permission related issue.